# Need Explanation for Display, Before, After Attribute and Pseudo-Classes in CSS

Tags: css, html

```css
nav.page-nav {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  line-height: 6rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}
nav.page-nav .container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}
nav.page-nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 9rem;
  padding: 0 1.8rem;
  border-right: 1px dotted #3d3d3d;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c3c3c3;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
nav.page-nav a:first-child {
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #3d3d3d;
}
nav.page-nav a:hover {
  color: #e4e4e4;
  background-color: black;
}
nav.page-nav .active {
  color: white;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#c95656, #8d0606);
  background: linear-gradient(#c95656, #8d0606);
}
nav.page-nav .active:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
nav.page-nav .active:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6rem;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin-left: -1.9rem;
  border-top: 2rem solid #8d0606;
  border-right: 6.5rem solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
nav.page-nav .active:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin-left: 4.3rem;
  border-top: 2rem solid #8d0606;
  border-left: 6.5rem solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<nav class="page-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="/index.htm" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="/about.htm">About</a>
    <a href="/schedule.htm">Schedule</a>
    <a href="/register.htm">Register</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I am confused with the `display: block` in the `nav.page-nav` a selector. If I change it to display: inline-block nothing change. Why?

I am also confused with the :before and :after. How do they work in the above code? I mean before supposed to be before the element no bellow it. They are shown bellow each active element.

Comment: `top: 6rem` on the `:before` is enough distance for it to appear beneath the element.

Comment: how about the sides? why is it not in the left bottom? How about the after element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common difference between `display:block and inline-block` is there alignment.

`Display:Block` by default takes full `width` and assigned `height` to there elements. Placement of `display:block` elements are one after another, whereas to align them in one line i.e. horizontally we need to use `float:left`, but `display:inline-block` elements are by default align in `inline` no need to used `float:left`.

`Pseudo ::before` - is used to assign some content or some style properties before the targeted element, but as you have assigned `top:6rem` to         `nav.page-nav .active:before` so your before element is at bottom of target element. 
`Pseudo ::after` - is used to assign some content or some style properties after the targeted element.

```css
nav.page-nav {
    background-color: #1d1d1d; 
    line-height: 6rem; 
    font-size: 1.7rem; 
}

/* TODO: nav.page-nav .container */
    nav.page-nav .container {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
    }

/* TODO: nav.page-nav a */
    nav.page-nav a {
        display: block;
        width: 9rem;
        padding: 0 1.8rem;
        border-right: 1px dotted #3d3d3d; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        color: #c3c3c3;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
            position:relative;
    }

/* TODO: nav.page-nav a:first-child */
        nav.page-nav a:first-child {
            border-left-width: 1px;
            border-left-color: #3d3d3d;
        }

/* TODO: nav.page-nav a:hover */
        nav.page-nav a:hover {
            color: #e4e4e4;
            background-color: black;
        }

/* TODO: nav.page-nav .active */
    nav.page-nav .active {
        color: white;
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(#c95656, #8d0606);
        background: linear-gradient(#c95656, #8d0606); 
    }


/* TODO: nav.page-nav .active:hover */
        nav.page-nav .active:hover {
            color: #fff;
        }

/* TODO: nav.page-nav .active:before */
        nav.page-nav .active:before {
            position: absolute;
            top:6rem;
            left:0;
            display: block;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            border-top: 2rem solid #8d0606;
            border-right: 6.5rem solid transparent;
            content: "";
        }

/* TODO: nav.page-nav .active:after */
        nav.page-nav .active:after {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            border-top: 2rem solid #8d0606;
            border-left: 6.5rem solid transparent;
            content: "";
            bottom:-2rem;
            right:0;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="page-nav">
<div class="container">
<a href="/index.htm" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="/about.htm">About</a>
<a href="/schedule.htm">Schedule</a>
<a href="/register.htm">Register</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: but this still did not answer my first question: am confused with the display: block in the nav.page-nav a selector. If I change it to display: inline-block nothing change. Why? If you look at the mentioned selector, there is no float: left. So why is it horizontally displayed?

Comment: @AymenKareem By default all div elements are display:block and as said they take full width if not assigned to them and auto height, you try display:block and display:inline-block in nav.page-nav  and you can find difference by seeing in background. Background spreads full in page when display:block, but when display is display:inline-block it doesn't.

Comment: Check this two fiddle clearly show the difference between inline-block and block elements. In your codes you have only one parent element so that's the reason that we could find difference between them.
 
https://jsfiddle.net/tdz2kduz/  

https://jsfiddle.net/5b1d9waz/